# Google OCR Api with OAuth 2

Tags: api, oauth, ocr

I try to upload image to google docs using code

I setup access_token and access_token_secret

$uri = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full?ocr=true';
$newDocumentEntry = $client->uploadFile($fileLocation, $fileName, $mimeType, $uri);
but i receive exception

"The field ocr is not supported in this request version"

without "?ocr=true"
upload is correct

is there any way to upload image with ocr ?

Answer (score -1):

OCR only works with version 3 of the API. Have you tried POSTing to .../full?v=3&ocr=true?

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Versioning